# Flatten Parent Child Objects Using UnderscoreJS

Tags: underscore.js

I have an array containing parent child relationship as shown below:

```
[{
    Company: 'ABC',
    Employees: [{ Company: 'ABC', Name: 'EMP-1' }, 
                { Company: 'ABC', Name: 'EMP-2' }, 
                { Company: 'ABC', Name: 'EMP-3' }]
},
{
    Company: 'XYZ',
    Employees: [{ Company: 'XYZ', Name: 'EMP-4' }, 
                { Company: 'XYZ', Name: 'EMP-5' }, 
                { Company: 'XYZ', Name: 'EMP-6' }]
}]
```

And using `UnderscoreJS`'s _.flatten method, I want to all elements at same level `0` as shown below:

```
[{ Company: 'ABC' }
 { Company: 'ABC', Name: 'EMP-1' }, 
 { Company: 'ABC', Name: 'EMP-2' }, 
 { Company: 'ABC', Name: 'EMP-3' },
 { Company: 'XYZ' }, 
 { Company: 'XYZ', Name: 'EMP-4' }, 
 { Company: 'XYZ', Name: 'EMP-5' }, 
 { Company: 'XYZ', Name: 'EMP-6' }]
```

But I don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an underscore solution that first [**maps**](http://underscorejs.org/#map) across the data to return an array of the company without the Employees array and the Employees array. These arrays are then [**flattened**](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten).

```
var result = _.chain(data)
    .map( company => [_.omit(company, 'Employees'), company.Employees])
    .flatten()
    .value();
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution with pure JS:

```js
var array = [{
    Company: 'ABC',
    Employees: [{ Company: 'ABC', Name: 'EMP-1' }, 
                { Company: 'ABC', Name: 'EMP-2' }, 
                { Company: 'ABC', Name: 'EMP-3' }]
},
{
    Company: 'XYZ',
    Employees: [{ Company: 'XYZ', Name: 'EMP-4' }, 
                { Company: 'XYZ', Name: 'EMP-5' }, 
                { Company: 'XYZ', Name: 'EMP-6' }]
}]

var result = array.reduce(function(store, object, index) {
  var arrayOfEmployees = object.Employees;

  delete object.Employees;
  store.push(object);

  return store.concat(arrayOfEmployees)
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```